# Uinavigation error while i press back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

First vc(view controller) has one button when i press it i have to go to second vc which embedded tab-bar controller.please check attached images.

[image]

At button click event i call tab bar like this :-

```
TabBarVC *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

now when i press it goes to tab-bar as desire but show me message :-
"Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."

now when i click on back button application crash and show me this error message :-

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'

**Possible solution** :- this may be cause because i call tabbar controller which is embeded on secondvc...
i set animation yes to no like this :-

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

so now application did not crash but when i press to back button it should go to firstvc but it again go to tabbar controller (same view controller).If i click 2 times in back button so it goes to firstvc as desired. Any suggestion how can i remove this navigation stack issue.

Comment: what is super class of TabBarVC?

Comment: I embeded tab bar controller in second view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you want this I guess it will help you solve your problem 
Note: -Username and Password are "praveen". I have attached the sample project to this link.
http://www.filedropper.com/tabbarapplicationwithlogin

Comment: Yes your example is working as desired but it is not working at my end :-
I add segue identifier (Identifier - pass and show eg push ) and on button click i add this : [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pass" sender:nil];
now i run app and i when i click on back button it show my same error i.e. "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'"
your example is working fine.Have you done anything else on this example? please suggest

Comment: Don't Perform segue just dismiss it please go through my coding.

Comment: instead of using segue i set tabbar contrller storyboard id to TabBarVC i use this to your code and problem resolved :-
ViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarVC"];
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:yes];
i am little bit confuse. at first line of code i am assigning tab bar controller to viewcontroller type and it's working.

Comment: in your example if i press on login button it show me tabbar and show first item i.e. "more" suppose i want to open different tab bar item after login how can i do this. i saw we can do this via setselectedindex method but do you have any example or link for it ?

Comment: no i don't have any code or link but will  update you shortly with the answer

Comment: Thanks praveen for your help.

Comment: UITabBarController *tbc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
tbc.selectedIndex=1;
[self presentViewController:tbc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: sorry,I do not understand.you mean i have make one class (TabbarContrller)which inherits from UItabbarcontrller. i will add this code to view load but how can i set index of different-2 tab  item ? Also i am not able to make outlate of tabbar controller. can you please give me some steps ?

Comment: No That's Just StoryBoard Identifier write that in button action from which you want to go to the TabBar. Give Your TabBarController StoryBoard Identifier  and write that here  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"arpitTabBarController"];